# Spring Batch Job to Process and Write each item Asynchronously

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm new to Spring Batch and was trying to go through some Multi threading approaches, but unable to determine which one will suit my need.

The flow I have:

1. **Reader** will pick up all documents from elastic search matching a doc_status (e.g. 'pending').(can be >=40 docs)
2. All these 'pending' docs are sent to **processor** - where we iterate each document and lot of heavy data processing happens for each(10s of sql queries executed, result Sets with 1M rows iterated - The queries here cannot be executed asynchronously as input to subsequent queries is dependent on results of previous.)
3. All the processed documents are then sent to **writer** where we update doc_status in elastic to 'completed'.

I want to Process and Write each doc independently.
Is there a way that after I fetch all the documents in Reader, I should be able to process and write each document using a separate thread?

Appreciate the help!

JobConfig:

```java
Job job1(){
return jobFactory.get("Job1")
             .listener(myListener())
             .start(step1())
             .build();
}

Step step1(){
return stepFactory.get("step1")
        .<List<Map<String, String>>, Map<String, Object>>
// Keeping the chunk size 1 as I want to process and write one doc at a time.
        chunk(1) 
       .reader(reader)
       .processor(processor)
       .writer(writer)
       .build();
}
```

Comment: You already do that with a chunk size of 1. To make it concurrent inject a task executor into the step.